# method is not getting called from within __new__

Tags: python, new-operator, init

in the below code i attempt to understand **init** and **new**. The problem I am having is the method callBeforeInit() is never called.

Please let me know why it is not getting called and how to have it called.

**code**:

```
class varargs:

def __new__(cls):
    print("in object creation")
    callBeforeInit()
    return super(varargs, cls).__new__(cls)
    #return object.__new__(cls)

def __init__(self):
    print("in object indtansiation")

def callBeforeInit():
    print("called before init")

v = varargs()
```

**error**:

```
in object creation
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\python workspace\Varargs.py", line 15, in <module>
v = varargs()
File "d:\python workspace\Varargs.py", line 5, in __new__
callBeforeInit()
NameError: name 'callBeforeInit' is not defined
```

Comment: Your code is not referring to a method - such as `cls.callBeforeInit` - it is referring to a lexically scoped callable - namely just `callBeforeInit`. As the error says, no such thing is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**new** is called before creating an object, so there is no such method exist at this point.

It should be

```
class varargs:

    def __new__(cls):
        print("in object creation")
        cls.callBeforeInit()
        return super(varargs, cls).__new__(cls)
        #return object.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        print("in object indtansiation")

    @classmethod
    def callBeforeInit(cls):
        print("called before init")

v = varargs()
```